# Use of ‘это’ after a dash

Tags: выбор-слова, пунктуация

Is there a particular significance to the use of это after a dash? For instance, I think *Москва — столица России* or *Москва — это столица России* mean the same thing. But I don't know the point of inserting это there. (In English it is wrong to stick "this is" in the middle of a sentence like that, saying "Moscow this is the capital of Russia".)

More generally, what is the distinction in meaning between А — Б, А — это Б?

Comment: это means it here, not this. Moscow - it is the capital if Russia.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally a dash is used here just as so called [copula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_%28linguistics%29) is used in English. So your guess is right, dash here is a some kind of punctuational copula, therefore can be translated as "is".

Though `— это` is indeed another form of such copula, there is a subtle difference between usage of these two forms. Roughly speaking, pure punctuational form is more universal, you can use it in a wider set of cases.

You can say, for example:

> Вы — подлец!

But this phrase will sound definitely unnatural to native speaker:

> Вы — это подлец.

So, with personal pronouns usage of `это` is untypical.

As for me, it is very difficult to describe exact rules for choosing one these forms, but here is a rule of thumb that can give you a hint. If you can imagine the phrase used in some kind of dictionary as an article, for example:

- Париж — столица Франции.
- Слон — млекопитающее.
- Солнце — звезда.

then you can use `— это` form.

Also, when you want to emphasise the second part of phrase, you can use `это`. So, when you can imagine this very phrase used with some adjective, it looks like you cane use `- это` form:

> Пётр — [это] [ужасный] негодяй.

Comment: Тире обычно не ставится, если подлежащее выражено личным местоимением, а сказуемое – именительным падежом существительного. http://rosental.virtbox.ru/punct_xxi.html § 79.8

Comment: @КуЪ - спасибо за ссылку, но вопрос не об этом и ответ не об этом :) Понятное дело, что тире - интонационное.

Answer (score 3):

> More generally, what is the distinction in meaning between А — Б, А — это Б?

@shabunc showed in his answer that not every `A — B` sentence can be used with `это`

When `это` is actually used there's, AFAIK, no practical difference in written form. But there is a difference in spoken language where `это` is a way to "pronounce" dash. Note, that actual verb in this sentences is omitted (in English, you would expect `is/are` somewhere) and without `это` meaning may become unclear. For example, these sentences:

> Музыка — радость!
>   Кирпичный завод — рабочие места, жилье и инвестиции

when used without context/great dramatic skills may sound unclear. Here `это` helps to clarify the meaning:

> Музыка — это радость!
>   Кирпичный завод — это рабочие места, жилье и инвестиции

You can safely use well-known phrases and obvious statements without `это`, for example:

> Время — деньги.
>   Знание — сила!
>   Волк — хищник!
>   Москва — столица России

**Side note:** [wiktionary entry on это](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE) mentions five different meanings. In this particular case `это` is a particle and not really equivalent to `this [is]`.

Comment: Do you know if this usage of это, to avoid confusion, is comparatively recent or has it been in use for a long time?

Comment: @KCd I'm not a linguist, but I don't think it's recent. Actually, I believe that `A — B` is a version with `это` omitted.

Comment: @KCd It is quite old. As for the difference in use, there is one structure where "это" is obligatory: «Водка — это отлично» / «История — это очень интересно». Note that here, «отлично» and «интересно» do not agree with a subject, so if you omit *это*, the sentence does not hold together.

Answer (score 2):

> Москва - столица России

This means your addressee knows Moscow, you just add something to it or underline this property.

> Москва - это столица России

This means you introduce new term, Moscow, which was prevuously unknown to your addressee, and define it as the capital of Russia.

Comment: An addition for a questioner: think about `... — это ...` like about a vocabulary-like definition.